# Fullname control is not working in Dynamics 365 Unified interface

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-uci

We've recently enabled the Unified Interface on our Dynamics 365 CE web client and noticed that the *fullname* is missing from the Contact forms and several views. It is there when we open the Form editor, but when we're running `formContext.getAttribute("fullname")` it returns a null.

It's causing us a big headache as we're using the fullname basically everywhere: in forms, views, Document templates, JavaScripts etc.

Has anyone come across this problem or knows a workaround without having to replace the *fullname* with first and last name everywhere in our environment?

According to Microsoft it's officially not ready before April 2020 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/about-unified-interface#capabilities-not-yet-on-unified-interface), but we need to start testing before that.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any better solution?

Comment: No, we did not unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Composite control is not available in UCI yet. So the popup will not be showing up to do data entry. That means the **Full name** field will display as the child individual fields, ie. **First name** & **Last name**. The data changes in any of the First name or Last name will replicate to Full name field.

Only changes needed is in form scripting. Whenever/wherever you are accessing the Full name field like `formContext.getAttribute("fullname")` just switch it to `formContext.getAttribute("firstname") + " " + formContext.getAttribute("lastname")` if the script is executing in UCI.

I just tested this quickly in my UCI. Also views showing the Full name field without issues. Templates should not be a problem if data is there. Only problem is in form, so the above script will solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks. It shows however that there isn't really 1 clever easy step for situation